# How to iterate in a Spatial Polygon Data Frame in R?

Tags: r, polygon, data-frame, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate in a SpatialPolygonDataFrame that contains 110 features.

I tried to use the following code with no success:

```
iterate.spdf = function(x){
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
        p = x[i,]
    }
    return(p)
}
```

It returns with a SpatialPolygonDataFrame that contains only one feature. The code seems to overwrite the polygons to end up with only one feature.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure reason of your code is because the `return()` statement is out of the loop, but if you place into the loop, the result will be the same. You need to create a list to store each polygon iterated:

```
# reproducible example
library(sp)
data(wrld_simpl, package='maptools')

# what you have
iterate.spdf = function(x){
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    p = x[i,]
  }
  return(p)
}

length(iterate.spdf(wrld_simpl))
## [1] 1

# a possible workaround
iterate.spdf = function(x){
  p = list()
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    p[[i]] = x[i,]
  }
  return(p)
}

length(iterate.spdf(wrld_simpl))
## [1] 246

class(iterate.spdf(wrld_simpl))
## [1] "list"
```

You can return a `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` object also:

```
# if you want to return a spdf object

library(raster)

iterate.spdf = function(x){
  p = list()
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    p[[i]] = x[i,]
  }
  return(do.call(rbind,p))
}

length(iterate.spdf(wrld_simpl))
## [1] 246
class(iterate.spdf(wrld_simpl))
## [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
## attr(,"package")
## [1] "sp"
```